# How to update the properties in multiple jobs created by abaqus script?

Tags: python, abaqus

1. I used the for loop to create iterative jobs to change the three properties i, j, m.
2. To specify the job name I used the property values.
3. Abaqus job name rule does not permit to use dot (decimal) in job names. So, I created another for loop with variables k, l, n, so that I can know the corresponding input file combination.
4. Then I included the script to save the force-time data from all jobs.

**Problem:**

**1.** My script creates multiple jobs and completes the simulation. **But,
the properties in all the input files are the same (Only the last
combination of for loop is in all input files). Why my for loop is
not updating the properties in the jobs? **
**2.** The Foce-Time file has different job names as expected, but all the values are the same.

```
for i in arange(0.05, 0.25, 0.05):
    for j in arange(0.35, 0.36, 0.01):
        for m in arange(1.67e-08, 1.68e-08, 1e-10):
            mdb.models['Model-1'].Material(name='Material-1')
            mdb.models['Model-1'].materials['Material-1'].Elastic(table=((i, j), ))
            mdb.models['Model-1'].materials['Material-1'].Permeability(
            inertialDragCoefficient=0.142887, specificWeight=9.81e-06, table=((
            m, 4.0), ))
            a = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
            session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=a)
            session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].assemblyDisplay.setValues(
                optimizationTasks=OFF, geometricRestrictions=OFF, stopConditions=OFF)
for k in range(5, 25, 5):
    for l in range(35, 36, 1):
        for n in range(167, 168, 1):
            mdb.Job(name='Job_'+'ym'+str(k)+'_'+'pr'+str(l)+'_'+'pe'+str(n), model='Model-1', description='', type=ANALYSIS, 
                atTime=None, waitMinutes=0, waitHours=0, queue=None, memory=90, 
                memoryUnits=PERCENTAGE, getMemoryFromAnalysis=True, 
                explicitPrecision=SINGLE, nodalOutputPrecision=SINGLE, echoPrint=OFF, 
                modelPrint=OFF, contactPrint=OFF, historyPrint=OFF, userSubroutine='', 
                scratch='', resultsFormat=ODB, numThreadsPerMpiProcess=1, 
                multiprocessingMode=DEFAULT, numCpus=1, numGPUs=0)
            mdb.jobs['Job_'+'ym'+str(k)+'_'+'pr'+str(l)+'_'+'pe'+str(n)].submit(consistencyChecking=OFF)
            mdb.jobs['Job_'+'ym'+str(k)+'_'+'pr'+str(l)+'_'+'pe'+str(n)].waitForCompletion()
            o3 = session.openOdb(
                name='Job_'+'ym'+str(k)+'_'+'pr'+str(l)+'_'+'pe'+str(n)+'.odb')
            session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=o3)
            session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].makeCurrent()
            a = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
            session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=a)
            session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(
                displayedObject=session.odbs['Job_'+'ym'+str(k)+'_'+'pr'+str(l)+'_'+'pe'+str(n)+'.odb'])
            odb = session.odbs['Job_'+'ym'+str(k)+'_'+'pr'+str(l)+'_'+'pe'+str(n)+'.odb']
            session.XYDataFromHistory(name='RF2 PI: rootAssembly N: 1 NSET RP-1', odb=odb, 
                outputVariableName='Reaction force: RF2 PI: rootAssembly Node 1 in NSET RP', 
                steps=('Step-1', 'Step-2', ), __linkedVpName__='Viewport: 1')
            x0 = session.xyDataObjects['RF2 PI: rootAssembly N: 1 NSET RP-1']
            session.writeXYReport(fileName='Job_'+'ym'+str(k)+'_'+'pr'+str(l)+'_'+'pe'+str(n)+'.txt', xyData=(x0, ))
```

I tried adding a wait comment after the for loop, but that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you first three `for` loops (of `i`, `j`, `m`), you are updating the material values. So, after the completion of these loops, the model will have the last material values. 
After that, in next three `for` loops (of `k`, `l`, `n`), you are creating the job from the same model which has lastly updated material values. Hence, you are getting the same input file. 
**Solution:** 
Merge both for loops - do material updating and job submission in the same `for` loops.
Try following updated code (modify further if required):

```
viewport = session.viewports['Viewport: 1']
for i in arange(0.05, 0.25, 0.05):
    for j in arange(0.35, 0.36, 0.01):
        for m in arange(1.67e-08, 1.68e-08, 1e-10):
            # k - i 100 - , l - j 100, n - m 1e8
            i_ = int(i*100)
            j_ = int(j*100)
            m_ = int(m*1e8)
            # Create job name based on loop values
            job_name = 'Job_ym%d_pr%d_pe%d' % (i_, j_, m_)

            # Update model - update material properties
            mat = mdb.models['Model-1'].Material(name='Material-1')
            mat.Elastic(table=((i, j), ))
            mat.Permeability(inertialDragCoefficient=0.142887,
                             specificWeight=9.81e-06, table=((m, 4.0), ))
            a = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
            viewport.setValues(displayedObject=a)
            viewport.assemblyDisplay.setValues(optimizationTasks=OFF,
                                               geometricRestrictions=OFF,
                                               stopConditions=OFF)

            # Create the job with updated model
            mdb.Job(name=job_name, model='Model-1', description='', type=ANALYSIS,
                atTime=None, waitMinutes=0, waitHours=0, queue=None, memory=90,
                memoryUnits=PERCENTAGE, getMemoryFromAnalysis=True,
                explicitPrecision=SINGLE, nodalOutputPrecision=SINGLE, echoPrint=OFF,
                modelPrint=OFF, contactPrint=OFF, historyPrint=OFF, userSubroutine='',
                scratch='', resultsFormat=ODB, numThreadsPerMpiProcess=1,
                multiprocessingMode=DEFAULT, numCpus=1, numGPUs=0)

            # Submit the job
            mdb.jobs[job_name].submit(consistencyChecking=OFF)
            mdb.jobs[job_name].waitForCompletion()
            odb = session.openOdb(name=job_name+'.odb')
            viewport.setValues(displayedObject=odb)
            viewport.makeCurrent()
            session.XYDataFromHistory(
                name='RF2 PI: rootAssembly N: 1 NSET RP-1', odb=odb,
                outputVariableName='Reaction force: RF2 PI: rootAssembly Node 1 in NSET RP',
                steps=('Step-1', 'Step-2', ), __linkedVpName__='Viewport: 1')
            x0 = session.xyDataObjects['RF2 PI: rootAssembly N: 1 NSET RP-1']
            session.writeXYReport(fileName=job_name+'.txt', xyData=(x0, ))
```